# Convert JSON string array to PHP array

Tags: php

I have a JSON array in PHP:

```
$array={"definitions":[
    {"text":"Informal One who is proficient at using or programming a computer; a computer buff.",
     "attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
    },
    {"text":"Informal One who uses programming skills to gain illegal access to a computer network or file.",
     "attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
    },
    {"text":"Informal One who enthusiastically pursues a game or sport: a weekend tennis hacker. ",
     "attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
    },
    {"text":"See hackie.",
     "attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
    }
]}
```

No matter what I try, I can't access the elements. I need to access the elements like this:
`$array[0]["definitions"][0]["text"]`.

Comment: It's my mistake, my array was actually a string.

Comment: Don't repost your own question. Someone with more than 1 rep should know better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built in library http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Or if you are running an older version of PHP I use the PEAR Servers_JSON (http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$data = json_decode($your_json_string, TRUE);
```

the second parameter will make decoded json string into an associative arrays.

for example

```
json_decode('{"foo":"bar"}', true); // returns array("foo" => "bar")
```